# Computing intersection of a function with a specific interval using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, intersection

I'm stuck trying to get functions that are existent in scipy (or sympy) for the following task:

Suppose we are given the following function:

```
f(A,B,C) = k1-A*sin(B*k2-C)
```

for each of the axis A,B,C of the space we have a specific interval, like [a_lb, a_ub], [b_lb, b_ub], [c_lb, c_ub], [d_lb, d_ub].

Which functions of scipy can be used to compute if the space encompassed by the boundaries is intersected by the given function? I thought of like e.g. computing the Hessian matrix.

Thank you for hints
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you are looking for is an answer to whether `f(A,B,C)` bounded in the domain `[a_l,a_u]x[b_l,b_u]x[c_l,c_u]` has a value within `[d_l,d_u]`. You can try using `scipy.optimize.minimize` for this.

If you run `scipy.optimize.minimize` on `f` with the bounds `[a_l,a_u]x[b_l,b_u]x[c_l,c_u]`, you should get the minimal value of `f` in the domain. Similarly, minimizing `-f` will give you the maximal value of `f` in the domain. `f` intersects the given boundary if and only if the interval `[fmin, fmax]` intersects the interval `[d_l,d_u]`.

Note that `scipy.optimize.minimize` is a non-linear optimization and therefore requires an initial guess. The middle point of the domain box is a natural choice, but since the non-linear optimization may encounter a local minimum (or not converge), you may want to try several other initial guesses as well. `scipy.optimize.minimize` has many (optional) parameters so I recommend you read its [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) and play with them to fine-tune your usage to your needs.